# Custom table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, etoc

I think Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics table of contents is really beautiful. How can I create it in `LaTeX`?

[image: Sakurai's table of contents]

I tried to use `etoc` and `tocloft` but I'm new to this stuff and couldn't make any real progress.

Comment: A marvelous book, indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special setups require special means ;-)

The `spacings` etc. can be done with `tocloft` features, however, this changes the `\tableofcontents` command too much.

The section page numbers in the section title line require some change to the `\@sect` command.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\let\latextableofcontents\tableofcontents % Save the original version
\makeatother


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\newlength{\commonindentshift}

\setlength{\commonindentshift}{15pt}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hfill$\blacksquare$\hfill}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\commonindentshift} % increase the space
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\commonindentshift}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{\commonindentshift}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{\commonindentshift}


\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\bfseries}

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\hskip\cftchapnumwidth #1}{\thepage}}
}  

\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\xpatchcmd{\latextableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
}{%
  \chapter*{%
    \centering \contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
}{\typeout{Patched!!!}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}
\let\tableofcontents\latextableofcontents

}


\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7 \textit{\thepage}}{}}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7 \textit{\thepage}}{}}}%
    \fi
  \@xsect{#5}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\tableofcontents


\starredchapter{Preface}
\starredchapter{In memoriam}


\chapter{First}
\section{First of first chapter}
\section{Second of first chapter}
\subsection{First sub section of 2nd section}
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don´t know if I did something wrong, but in ShareLaTeX this doesn't look a lot like Sakurai's.
The letter size of the chapters is smaller than in Sakurai's, it still has dots, the square isn't all black, the alignment is wrong and so on...

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: I am not yet finished ;-)

Comment: Beautiful!
Just one last thing: how can I make the preface and "last note" align with the chapters? (like the "in memorian" in Sakurai's work)?

Comment: and the page of the sections right after it's title?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: The page numbers of the sections in the section title is possible, but I don't recommend this.

Comment: Right. So, there's a way to make the chapter pages numbers bigger? (To make clear that "this page number" is the beggining of a chapter)

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: See the update, please

Comment: It does not compile.

"File ended while scanning use of \g@addto@macro."

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: Yes, I posted the wrong version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39037/discussion-between-gabriel-ribeiro-and-christian-hupfer).