# Styled table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to create a styled table of contents which is based on the answer(s) on this question: [How to change style and color of Table of Content?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content)

The TeX I have is shown below:

```
\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{241,129,39}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{247,247,247}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{177,177,177}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptctitle,hidealllines=true]}{}{}

\titlecontents{section}
  [3.3em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-3em}\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax}{0pt}}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [3.3em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{0pt}}

\titlecontents{lsubsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{0pt}}

\titlecontents{subsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{0em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\@tempdima
      \hskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth\fboxsep100pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily#1%
          \nobreak\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}}\par\smallskip
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand\PartialToC{%

\startcontents[chapters]%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]
\printcontents[chapters]{1}{1}{\colorbox{ptctitle}{%

  \parbox[t][][t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \strut\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[.5em]{%
      }\large Contents}}\vskip5pt}
\end{mdframed}%
}
```

The problem is that the background of the 'Content' bar is not flush with the background as shown in the image below:

[image: TeX question]

Ideally I would like the dark gray rectangle to match up to the height and width of the lighter background. I've been trying for a while but I can't seem to figure it out (to be honest, I don't fully understand the code provided in the answer prior to this). It seems so trivial. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Isn't there something like a styled-toc-package?

Comment: You should read a bit of this package here:  
http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: No, `titletoc` and `tocloft` do not go well together!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm pretty sure, you are right, since you know more than me. On the other hand, ses did not state, that something like mintoc is needed. If it is needed, tocloft works according to its docu with minitoc.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I did not mention `minitoc` at all ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But it is mentioned in the referenced question and seems to be one reason, why titletoc has been chosen there.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I didn't click on the link. Well, it's a `titlesec`/`titletoc` question and I don't like those packages, so I will not answer

Comment: Well, regardless of the packages, I'm open to other suggestions of course

Comment: Look here and read the docu of tocloft: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306652/custom-table-of-contents I think, this should lead you, where you want to go.

Comment: @ses: If you want to have somebody really answering this question, you should provide a compilable code, not a fragment

Answer (score 1):

So you never posted a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), but since the problem seemed pretty simple, I put one together from [the question you referenced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content).  You need to add a single line:

```
\mdfsetup{innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt}
```

That will do it for all the boxes in your TOC.  Note that simply reading the `mdframed` documentation would have solved this problem for you.  Adding that before you do any `mdframed` commands should yield you the following:

[image: Color TOC]

Which I think is what you want.  Hope that helps.  Please read through creating a MWE, however; you'd likely get a *much* quicker and more thorough answer.